# model gets correct input dimensions, but throws dimension error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-2, tensorflow2.0

**Edit: Solved. Spelling mistake, see first comment**

---

- I use a MobileNetV2 pretrained model in Keras2/TF2

  - My images are scaled to 224x224
  - I set the model input shape: `input_shape=(224,224,3)`

Later I use ImageGenerator to create the images. Here I set

- `data_format='channels_last'`

as the model needs the channels at position 2 (0,1,2).

then in `flow_from directory` I set

- `target_size=[224,224]`

When I then fit the model, I receive this error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_8 to have shape
>   (224, 224, 3) but got array with shape (244, 244, 3)

---

Could it be that using `channels_last` in the Generator options lets the target in `flow_from_directory` be identify the dimensions wrongly as channel?

Or checking the error traceback  `extract_tensors_from_dataset=True` reads the dimensions from the file rather than my given input_shape. In the (keras1) manual it reads :

> ...you can also omit this option if you would like to infer input_shape
>   from an input_tensor. If you choose to include both input_tensor and
>   input_shape then input_shape will be used if they match, if the shapes
>   do not match then we will throw an error. E.g. (160, 160, 3) would be
>   one valid value...

For me it looks like it takes the input_shape from the tensor, and then throws an error as the shape does not match...which it actually does.

also `input_tensor` is default None and I did not change it.

Does anyone know what is going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Might be stupid, but isn't a simple writting error ? Check if you are resizing your images to (224, 224, 3) and not to (244, 244, 3)
Because the error say you are feeding data with the wrong size to the network

Comment: Aahhhhh, Read it undret times but my brain autocorrected it to 224... :-) Thanks sometimes you just need a new pair of eyes

Comment: Ahah it happen so many times ! Glad to have helped you ;)